# You must provide a value expression following the '-' operator

Tags: powershell, cmd, expression

I have a some code in PowerShell and I need to use it in cmd.exe

I am using this command in cmd.exe

```
powershell -command "command"
```

But it gives me this error

```
At line:1 char:72
+ ... nt D:\15.txt -TotalCount 3)[-1] | Foreach-object {$_ -replace REG_SZ, ...
+                                                                  ~
You must provide a value expression following the '-replace' operator.
At line:1 char:73
+ ... 5.txt -TotalCount 3)[-1] | Foreach-object {$_ -replace REG_SZ,  } | F ...
+                                                            ~~~~~~
Unexpected token 'REG_SZ' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:79
+ ... .txt -TotalCount 3)[-1] | Foreach-object {$_ -replace REG_SZ,  } | Fo ...
+                                                                 ~
Missing argument in parameter list.
At line:1 char:113
+ ... -object {$_ -replace REG_SZ,  } | Foreach-object {$_ -replace Gmail,  ...
+                                                                  ~
You must provide a value expression following the '-replace' operator.
At line:1 char:114
+ ... t {$_ -replace REG_SZ,  } | Foreach-object {$_ -replace Gmail,  } | s ...
+                                                             ~~~~~
Unexpected token 'Gmail' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:119
+ ...  {$_ -replace REG_SZ,  } | Foreach-object {$_ -replace Gmail,  } | se ...
+                                                                 ~
Missing argument in parameter list.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpectedValueExpression
```

My command is :

```
powershell -command "(Get-Content D:\15.txt -TotalCount 3)[-1] | Foreach-object {$_ -replace "REG_SZ", " "} | Foreach-object {$_ -replace "Gmail", " "} | set-content D:\15.txt"
```

Comment: Does this work? powershell -command "(Get-Content D:\15.txt -TotalCount 3)[-1] | Foreach-object {$_ -replace \"REG_SZ\", \" \"} | Foreach-object {$_ -replace \"Gmail\", \" \"} | set-content D:\15.txt"

Comment: yes , in powershell but not in cmd

Comment: yes , does work , i forget ""

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use doublequotes to wrap the command and inside the command itself. `Cmd.exe/Powershell.exe` will end the command at the next double quote which is at `"REG_SZ"` in this example. Try using single quotes inside the command:

```
powershell -command "(Get-Content D:\15.txt -TotalCount 3)[-1] | Foreach-object {$_ -replace 'REG_SZ', ' '} | Foreach-object {$_ -replace 'Gmail', ' '} | set-content D:\15.txt"
```

Comment: Or just escape the double quotes using the backtick character (ie. `")

Comment: But that's just ugly considering he doesn't need variable-expansion anyways. :-)

Comment: but i can use doublequotes to wrap the command and inside the command itself by ()

Comment: Huh? You can't use the same type of quote to wrap a string while you're also using it inside the string (without escaping).

Answer (score 2):

Consider using `powershell.exe -EncodedCommand`. To use that, you would Base64 the command you want to run, and send the encoded string on the command line. The command text must be Unicode though. Running `powershell.exe /?` gives you an example at the very end of how to do this:

```
# To use the -EncodedCommand parameter:
$command = 'dir "c:\program files" '
$bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($command)
$encodedCommand = [Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)
powershell.exe -encodedCommand $encodedCommand
```

The nice thing about this is that you don't have to worry about any special characters, even newlines, being misinterpreted by the command prompt parser. You could write your code in a script file and then just convert that whole thing:

```
# To use the -EncodedCommand parameter:
$command = (Get-Content C:\myscript.ps1) -join "`n"
$bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($command)
$encodedCommand = [Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)
powershell.exe -encodedCommand $encodedCommand
```

---

With your command:

```
$command = @"
(Get-Content D:\15.txt -TotalCount 3)[-1] | Foreach-object {$_ -replace "REG_SZ", " "} | Foreach-object {$_ -replace "Gmail", " "} | set-content D:\15.txt
"@

$bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($command)
$encodedCommand = [Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)
powershell.exe -encodedCommand $encodedCommand
```

Comment: Agreed. Or he could create a script for this and use `-File "c:\myscript.ps1"`. That's what i prefer :-)

Comment: so i try your answer bet he tell me "is not recognized as the name
of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try
again.
At line:1 char:1"

Comment: @Yahya-_ I would need to see the actual code you tried to see where you're getting that error

Comment: the actual code "(Get-Content D:\15.txt -TotalCount 3)[-1] | Foreach-object {$_ -replace \"REG_SZ\", \" \"} | Foreach-object {$_ -replace \"Gmail\", \" \"} | set-content D:\15.txt | certutil -decode D:\15.txt D:\125.txt" | Start-Sleep -s 60"  to base64 by converter

Comment: @Yahya-_ Don't escape the double quotes

Comment: I found the solution in the Supreme but i want try your idea my command : "(Get-Content D:\15.txt -TotalCount 3)[-1] | Foreach-object {$_ -replace 'REG_SZ', ' '} | Foreach-object {$_ -replace 'Gmail', ' '} | set-content D:\15.txt | certutil -decode D:\15.txt D:\125.txt" how i can write it

Comment: thanks you command is right but in powershell but i want in cmd

Comment: @Yahya-_ the snippet provided shows how to obtain `$encodedCommand` which is a string you can send to `powershell.exe -encodedCommand` from `cmd.exe`. It allows you to avoid worrying about quotes and other special characters. By all means use whichever works for you, I'm just offering an alternative that may work better in some situations, or may be more appealing to you.